# Using expressions inside $slice

Tags: aggregation-framework

I am paginating an array field with $slice. Since $slice doesn't accept a negative position and a negative n, I need to use an expression to truncate n when position + array size < 0. This is to prevent the last page from containing elements that are in the previous page. Ideally I would be able to do something like this:

```
$slice: ['$messages',
      -1*parseInt(req.body.page)*20,
      (('$size: $messages') - parseInt(req.body.page)*20)<0?
      (('$size: $messages') - (parseInt(req.body.page) - 1)*20):20]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround by adding len to projection and slicing duplicate elements.